# O que é e como usar o ListViewAnimations?

Tags: android, listview, animação

Queria entender o que o `ListViewAnimations` é (um componente, um Framework?) e como ele funciona.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### O que é?

O [`ListViewAnimations`](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) é uma biblioteca de código livre para Android que permite que você adicione animações em itens do [`ListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) facilmente, como pode ser visto no exemplo:

---

**Exemplo de uso da biblioteca**
[image: Exemplo de uso da biblioteca]

---

Você pode efetuar o download e conferir tutoriais de uso, assim como mais informações [neste link](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations).

### Como funciona? — Instalação

A biblioteca consiste em módulos separados:

- `lib-core`: o núcleo da biblioteca, também contém *[appearence animations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/wiki/Appearance-Animations)* (*fade-in*).
- `lib-manipulation`: contém as manipulações dos itens do `ListView`, como o "Arraste-para-Ocultar" (*Swype-to-Dimiss*) e o "Arrastar-e-Soltar" (famoso, *Drag-and-Drop*)
- `lib-core-slh`: uma extensão do `lib-core` para suportar o [`StickyListHeaders`](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders).

---

**Exemplo de uso do** [`StickyListHeaders`](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)
[image: Exemplo de uso do StickyListHeaders]

---

Agora você tem três opções:

Adicionar o seguinte no seu `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core-slh:3.1.0@aar'
}
```

**Ou** você pode fazer o download de alguns arquivos:

- [`lib-core`](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/releases/download/3.1.0/listviewanimations_lib-core_3.1.0.jar)
- [`lib-manipulation`](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/releases/download/3.1.0/listviewanimations_lib-manipulation_3.1.0.jar)
- [`lib-core-slh`](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/releases/download/3.1.0/listviewanimations_lib-core-slh_3.1.0.jar)
- [`NineOldAndroids.jar`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/downloads)

Os arquivos .jar devem ser adicionados à sua pasta `libs` ou adicione-os como *jars* externos no caminho do build do seu projeto.

**Ou** você também pode adicionar o seguinte ao seu `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nhaarman.listviewanimations</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nhaarman.listviewanimations</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-manipulation</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nhaarman.listviewanimations</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-core-slh</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

### Como funciona? — Mãos à obra!

Agora que você já instalou tudo, vamos às animações em um `ListView`.

**1. *Appearance animations (fade-in)***

Esta animação serve como um *fade-in* (animação na opacidade de um objeto ou mídia, aumentando crescentemente em função do tempo).

[image: Exemplo]

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(myAdapter);
animationAdapter.setAbsListView(mListView);
mListView.setAdapter(animationAdapter);
```

Você pode criar seu próprio `AnimationAdapter`, ou use um dos predefinidos, que são:

- `AlphaAnimationAdapter`
- `ScaleInAnimationAdapter`
- `SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter`
- `SwingLeftInAnimationAdapter`
- `SwingRightInAnimationAdapter`

No exemplo, foi usado o `AlphaInAnimationAdapter`.

**2. DynamicListView**

O `DynamicListView` é uma classe que dispõe de efeitos como o Drag-and-Drop, Swype-to-Dismiss e animações de remover, mover e inserir itens. Foi feita para combinar as descrições acima de forma conveniente.

Primeiramente inclua isto no seu layout XML:

```
<com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.DynamicListView
        android:id="@+id/dynamiclistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**3. *Drag and Drop***

Para fazê-lo, chame por `enableDragAndDrop()` na sua `DynamicListView` e *sete* quais serão os itens que possam ser elegíveis para serem pegos (*drag*), para isso você pode usar o `TouchViewDraggableManager`:

```
mDynamicListView.enableDragAndDrop();
mDynamicListView.setDraggableManager(new TouchViewDraggableManager());
```

Você também pode iniciar o *drag* usando `startDraggin(int)`, por exemplo em um `OnItemLongClickListener`:

```
mDynamicListView.enableDragAndDrop();
mDynamicListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(
    new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                       final int position, final long id) {
            mDynamicListView.startDragging(position);
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

> <sub>**Nota:** esta funcionalidade só é possível em aparelhos que rodem ICS (API 14) ou superior.</sub>

Para outros efeitos, você pode dar uma olhada [nesta página](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/#getting-started) <sub>em inglês</sub>.

<sub>Retirado [daqui](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) — em tradução livre</sub>

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Não encontrei nada sobre `ListViewAnimation` na documentação oficial, provavelmente você está citando o [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations), que é uma lib que te auxilia em animações relacionadas a `ListViews` e `GridViews`. Quanto ao uso, tem uma aplicação de [exemplo](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/tree/master/example) no repositório, a integração é razoavelmente bem exemplificada.